# CORS Issue in SAP OData Service - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Is Present

Tags: jquery, sapui5, hana

This CORS issue is stuck mad with no solution. I am creating XSODOTA service in SAP HANA with below xsaccess file contents and consuming UI5 application in my localhost.

```
{
    "exposed": true,
    "authentication": [{
        "method": "Basic"
    }],
    "mime_mapping": [{
        "extension": "jpg",
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg"
    }],
    "force_ssl": false,
    "enable_etags": true,
    "prevent_xsrf": true,
    "anonymous_connection": null,
    "cors": [{
        "enabled": true,
        "allowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "OPTIONS"
        ],
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "maxAge": "3600"
    }],
    "headers": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
    "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store",
    "default_file": "index.html"
}
```

I have done all that and I can collect from SAP forums in XS Admin tool as below:

[image]

Calling the service in jQuery ajax function as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "odataurl?$format=json",
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    jsonpCallback: 'processJSON',
    headers : {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.d.results);
        that.onbindTable(msg.d.results);
    },
    error: function(err) {
    }
});
```

> Failed to load `http://odataurl?$format=json`: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:20019' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Try replace `"allowOrigin": "*"` to `"allowOrigin": ["*"]` in the cors config. The  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header should present in the server response, you don't have to put it in the request.
Check out this answer: [https://answers.sap.com/questions/65623/cors-issue-accessing-xsodata.html](https://answers.sap.com/questions/65623/cors-issue-accessing-xsodata.html)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your list of Allowed Headers is not correctly entered. They should be one entry per line, whereas you have a long comma separated list of headers in one line. this won't work. so either in you .xsaccess file or in the SAP HANa Admin tool, you need to set up the headers as individual values.

as an example, your .xsaccess file might look like this:

```
     "cors" :                      
            {
             "enabled" : true,
              "allowMethods": [
                                 "GET",
                                 "POST",
                                 "HEAD",
                                 "PUT",
                                 "OPTIONS"],
             "allowOrigin" : ["*"],
             "allowHeaders" : ["crossdomain","X-Requested-With","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers","Accept-Encoding","Sec-Fetch-Mode","Sec-Fetch-Site","authorization","Accept","Origin","Content-Type","Content-Length","content-encoding","Depth","User-Agent","Cache-Control","x-csrf-token","x-sap-cid","Accept-Language"],
             "exposeHeaders" : ["x-csrf-token","access-control-allow-headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","access-control-expose-headers","authorization"]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in b1s.conf
normaly in

```
vim /usr/sap/SAPBusinessOne/ServiceLayer/conf/b1s.conf
```

add:

```
{
  (...)
  "LicenseServer": "-----:40000",
"CorsEnable": true,
 "CorsAllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:8080;http://other:8080"
}
```

then

```
/etc/init.d/b1s stop
/etc/init.d/b1s start
```